# Layout Page in feature module with routing

Tags: angular, angular-router

I've followed [lazy-loading-ngmodules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)  tutorial so that I have App Module with routing and a Feature Modules with routing:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

app.component.html contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

How do I specify Layout component, that all pages within FeatureModule will use the same Layout? It is possible to have another `router-outlet` in FeatureModule?

EDIT:
So I have modified my FeatureModuleRouting:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: 'index',
        component: IndexComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule { }
```

and LayoutComponent:

```
<h2>Feature works!</h2>

<button routerLink="index">Home</button>
<button routerLink="about">About</button>
<router-outlet name='sub'></router-outlet>
```

but Index and About components are not loading into LayoutComponent. Why?

Comment: Do you want to divide your page layout (eg. header, footer in components) and use same in other components or modules ?

Comment: No. I know I can do it, but I would like to avoid it if possible

Comment: Have a look on below answer

Answer (score 1):

> Yes it's possible to have another router-outlet by **specifying name to
>   each router-oulet.**

In your Layout.Component.html

```
<router-outlet name="index"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="about"></router-outlet>
```

In route.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/layout',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        component: IndexComponent,
        name:'index'
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: AboutComponent,
        name:'about'

      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule { }
```

Whenever you route to /layout (you can change it to / if you don't want to route to /layout) both index and about component loaded into layout component.